# Security leak in TBB 3.6.2! Leaking information about installed fonts

Tags: security

No matter what I do, what add-on I installed up to now. 
On chrome://stopfingerprinting/content/common/options.html my TBB 3.6.2 reveals exactly what fonts I've installed, making me obviously identifiable.
This is a clear and open threat and should be solved somehow (making only some general basic fonts public or so).

Does anybody know an add-on that would eliminate this in the meantime?

Comment: Dear, use Tor browser bundle. Do not use chrome. There are more leaks with chrome that one can handle at this time.

Comment: Add-on in itself is a fingerprint.

Comment: You may disable script. It may help somewhat.